# Google App Engine redirect outgoing requests to Compute Engine proxy

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, reverse-proxy, squid

I currently have a Google App Engine web service set up in Java that makes outgoing http requests to other Google APIs. In order to secure my Google API keys, I can add IP address restrictions/whitelisting, but I cannot do this since App Engine does not have static IPs.

The solution I've found is to create a VM via Google Compute Engine (with a static IP), and install a Squid proxy server to redirect the requests.

Once Squid is installed on the VM, how can I actually redirect my requests from App Engine through the proxy server? I don't have much experience with proxy configuration, and have not been able to find any solid answers supporting a Java web app.

Comment: If you want to use App Engine with other GCP services and API’s, it may help to take a look at [Setting Up Authentication for Server to Server Production Applications](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production)

Comment: You need to use tunneling (HTTP or SSH) from App Engine to Compute Engine. I have done this before using an SSH tunnel. The code is simple for the client (App Engine). The SSH tunnel uses the SSH server built-into GCE to forward requests to the Internet. I have not written the client side in Jave but you should be able to find a few examples on the Internet. It is very easy to do in Go and Python.

Comment: This article explains SSH Remote Forwarding Tunnels. https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example#sec-Remote-Forwarding Ignore the point about SSH as this does not matter to your software. This technique just forward TCP traffic over the tunnel. SSH is just one of the methods but an easy one.

Answer (score 0):

If the API calls are not required to be realtime from your app engine service, you can route them through cloud tasks and create HTTP Target tasks that target your compute engine VM with static IP address. The handler can then forward it to other APIs.

Comment: The API requests do need to be realtime, since the app engine service is called from a client application